# C - Counting Numbers {making a program}

Tags: c

I am stuck with this difficult question. Would you please guide me in solving this question? Along with the coding you provide, also do give a simple, and easy-to-understand explanation; I mean, how did you did it(the logics), explain what you did in each step and why. This would greatly help me increase my coding skill and capability.

> In a class, there are some unknown no. of students. Recently, they
>   gave an exam and today the teacher is giving away their exam copies.
>   The teacher wants to find the number which is obtained by most of the
>   students and the number of students who obtained that number.
>
> - **Input Specification**
>     **:** The first line contains a positive integer T (T <= 100)), number of test case. In your coding lines, the first integer will be N - the
>     number of students. After that N integers will follow which are the
>     marks of the students. A student will obtain mark between 0 and 100
>     inclusive.
> - **Output Specification**
>     **:** For each case, print the case number, then the two integers where the first one is the number with maximum frequency and then the
>     frequency of that marks. If several such outputs are possible, output
>     the one with the maximum mark.

I tried something...... ineffective though..

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <dos.h> 

int main () 
{ 
 int stud_no; 
 clrscr();

 printf("\nEnter the total no. of students:"); 
 scanf("%d", &stud_no); 
 printf("%d", stud_no); 

 // Can't go on more 
 /* Need Help*/

 getchar(); 
 return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's un-attempted homework.

Comment: This is one question of NHSPC 2015 in Bangladesh. Don't think I am cheating , it is after the contest, now. Just can't do it!

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>

int main ()
{
int stud_no;

printf("\nEnter the total no. of students:");
scanf("%d", &stud_no);
printf("%d", stud_no);

printf("\nEnter each no. of %d students:", stud_no);
while (stud_no )
scanf()

getchar();
return 0;
}

Comment: You have to show us what you tried

Comment: 'Help!  Urgent!  Bold!'  will guarantee you down/close votes.  Nobody here wants to do all your work for you.  This is not a question, it's a work request:(

Comment: please [edit]  the question and add the code there.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine - edit the code into the question, please.

Comment: Plz, dont vote it as off-topic question. See, I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  Reading the inputs?  Designing the algorithm?

Comment: @soha we understand, that is why we are trying to help you. Notice my very first comment, take your time to read the contents on the links and then come back and look at your own question. You'll understand.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine we don't care if you're new, old or even if you're a Republican.  We only look at the question quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int T;

    scanf("%d", &T);
    for(int i = 1; i <= T; ++i){
        int marks[101] = {0};
        int max = -1;
        int n, mark;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j){
            scanf("%d", &mark);
            if(mark > max)
                max = mark;
            ++marks[mark];
        }
        printf("case %d : max = %d, frequency = %d\n", i, max, marks[max]);
    }

    getchar(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [DEMO](http://ideone.com/tNbwPq)

Comment: Thank You. You solved the problem, correctly. I am extremely grateful to you.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the requirements, your input looks something like this:

```
3
5 90 91 75 34 78
4 20 20 45 78
6 87 44 73 91 91 90
```

You have 3 test cases: test case 1 gives the scores for 5 students, test case two gives the scores for 4 students, and test case 3 gives the scores for 6 students.

For each test case, you print out the maximum score and the number of times that score appears:

```
Test case 1: max score = 91, number of students = 1 out of 5
Test case 2: max score = 78, number of students = 1 out of 4
Test case 3: max score = 91, number of students = 2 out of 6
```

or something along those lines.

So, you need to think in terms of the following operations:

1. Get the number of test cases
2. For each test case, get the number of scores
3. Read the scores
4. Determine the max score, and the number of times that score appears
5. Print the result for that test case
6. Go back to 2

You should not need to use any arrays for this; you only need to keep track of the maximum score and the number of times you've seen it for any given test case.

Now, if you have a specific problem with any of the above steps, please ask, and we'll do what we can to steer you in the right direction.  But nobody's going to write your code for you.  You have to show us what you've done.

Comment: I have shown my coding.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine - yeah, we noticed that.  Let's just say that it's less than complete... :(

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine: You're going to have to give us more than "Can't go on, need help".  What *specifically* do you need help with?  What part of the challenge do you not understand?   Is it a matter of how to structure the code?  Is it a matter of C syntax?